Validity of approximation method for von Mangoldt function
I'm working on a problem involving the pointwise almost everywhere convergence of multilinear ergodic averages with the von Mangoldt function inspired by this paper. Specifically, I'm looking at averages of the form:
$$
A_N(x) = \mathbb{E}_{n \in [1,N]} \Lambda(n) f_1(T^{P_1(n)}x) f_2(T^{P_2(n)}x) \ldots f_k(T^{P_k(n)}x)
$$
where $\Lambda(n)$ is the von Mangoldt function, $T$ is a measure-preserving transformation, and $P_i(n)$ are polynomials.
After considering various approaches, I've developed a hybrid method to approximate $\Lambda(n)$. At a high level, this what I've tried:

Truncate $\Lambda_M(n)$
$$
   \Lambda_M(n) = \begin{cases}
   \Lambda(n) & \text{if } n \leq M, \\
   0 & \text{otherwise}.
   \end{cases}
   $$
where $M = N^\theta$ for some $0 < \theta < 1$.

Decompose $\Lambda_M(n)$ into structured and pseudorandom parts
$$
   \Lambda_M(n) = \Lambda_{\text{str}}(n) + \Lambda_{\text{rand}}(n)
   $$

For the structured part, I've tried
$$
   \Lambda_{\text{str}}(n) = \sum_{p \leq M^{1/2}} \log p \cdot \mathbf{1}_{p | n}
   $$

Ensure that the pseudorandom part satisfies
$$
   \|\Lambda_{\text{rand}}\|_{U^{d+1}[N]} \leq \epsilon(N)
   $$
where $U^{d+1}[N]$ is the Gowers uniformity norm.

To further refine this, I've considered a Fourier-based approach for $\Lambda_{\text{str}}(n)$:
$$
   \Lambda_{\text{str}}(n) = \sum_{|\xi| \leq K} \hat{\Lambda}(\xi) e^{2\pi i \xi n / N}
   $$
where $K$ is chosen such that $\sum_{|\xi| > K} |\hat{\Lambda}(\xi)|^2 \leq \epsilon(N)$.

I'm trying to control the overall approximation error by ensuring
$$
   \|\Lambda - \Lambda_M\|_{U^{d+1}[N]} \leq \delta(N)
   $$
where $\delta(N) \to 0$ as $N \to \infty$.


Is this a valid approximation method for $\Lambda(n)$ in the context of multilinear ergodic averages? Are there any potential issues or improvements I should consider? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

What counts as success here? Put another way, what kind of approximation of the von Mangoldt function (with respect to this Gowers norm) would give you the desired results concerning the function $A_N(x)$?
